# Select dataframe rows based on column value

Tags: python, dataframe, search, nlp

I have a dataframe with one column containing words (concepts) and six other columns containing the sentiment for each word (e.g., joy, sadness,... with 0 and 1 values). I want to be able to calculate for each instance of a dataset the number of words belonging to each sentiment.

E.g.:

```
concept   joy    sadness    surprise   ...
security   1        0           0      ...
shame      0        1           0      ...
```

For a sentence containing both words that appear in the above example (and assuming that none of the other words are in the lexicon), I should have a score of `joy = 1`, `sadness = 1` and the remaining sentiments = 0.

I am trying to search either for an exact match of the word or a match with the lemmatized word of my sentence (there appears to be a mix between this two in the lexicon).

I tried this:

```
instance = "The security camera broke one day after I bought it. That's such a shame!"

for word in instance:
    lemmatized_word = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)
    df1 = lexicon[lexicon['Concepts'].str.contains(word, case = False, na = False)] 
    df2 = lexicon[lexicon['Concepts'].str.contains(lemmatized_word, case = False, na = False)]
```

in order to obtain another dataframe containing all the words belonging to the lexicon that appear in the sentence so I can later sum over all the other columns.

Not only the returned dataframe is not what I was expecting (it contains lots of extra rows that shouldn't be there), but as I'm quite new, I'm also not sure if this is the right approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you elaborate,  what is your expected output  given the instance statement..

Comment: @qaiser Hi! I will elaborate as maybe my previous description wasn't sufficient. I have a dataset containing comments, as well as a lexicon containing words and their associated emotion (the words can express at least one of the six possible emotions). For each instance in the dataset I want to be able to count how many words appear in each of the lexicons emotions. Basically, I want to use these emotions as additional features along with the dataset.